# Applet error: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission")

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to make an Applet, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Whenever I open my HTML file, it asks me security questions, but then I get: Error. Click for details.  This is what it says: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.0")

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<applet code = "Odyssey.class" archive = "Odyssey.jar" width = 600 height = 600>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Here is my Odyssey.class:

```
public class Odyssey extends Applet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static String windowName = "The Odyssey - Alpha 1.0";
public static JFrame window;

public static int WIDTH = 600, HEIGHT = 600;

public void init() {

    window = new JFrame(windowName);

    window.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    window.setVisible(true);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("Game is in a pop up window!", 20, 20);
}

}
```

Any reason why this isn't working?

If you really need this, I get this in the details:

```
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/The%20Odyssey/Odyssey.jar]:   
updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Tue Mar 18 20:11:16 CDT 2014,length=1712 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your program (where the error message is pointing to and you haven't posted), you're trying to call `System.exit`, which isn't permitted for the applet.

Comment: I'm not calling System.exit anywhere in my code......?  I'm not getting any error messages when I open details of the error.  I'm getting a bunch of stuff before that, but's that's not error code.

Comment: I'm not even getting any stacktrace, just a popup window with those details (posted above)